# Can I access (via internet) files from flash drive plugged-in router Huawei EchoLife hg8245h with a USB?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, routing, wireless-router

I have a router Huawei EchoLife hg8245h. It has an USB port. I want to use files in a flash drive pluggd-in that router, but outside of the home network (via HTTP or FTP, I guess).

Is that possible and how ?